# How to set formula by using google spreadsheets app script?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Actually, question is  - how to recreate type of formulas: 
 **ArrayFormula(replace(replace(regexreplace(K1:K&"","[-/,. ()]",""),4,0,"-"),8,0,"-"))**
into code. Unfortunately, i didn't find it by myself, so I'm asking for help.

Upd.
Let me clarify just a little.
Part of code which was used by me into script:

`value = value.replace(/^ /, '').replace(/[. )]/g, 'a').replace(/[+]/g, '').replace(/(aa)/g, '-').replace(/(a)/g, '-').replace(/[(]/g, '-');
value = value.replace(/^-/, '');
value = value.replace(/-$/, ''); range2.setValue(value);`

This is example of a result:
"(22)road.CA" - "22-road-CA";
"22roadCA" - is not(eror).
If we working into google spreadsheets we could use formula's which I'm typed before, and in this case, results will be the:
"(22)road.CA" - "22-road-CA";
"22roadCA" - "22-road-CA".
So, how to create right code for it? Mb I should delete all signs, use looping method for check sign by sign, and insert my variant after some count of cell array?

Comment: Could you explain the problem and your code as to what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take your time to read through the following article, as it will give you some hints on how to ask a question that is most likely to get answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: TO yuvraj zohan:
It looks like changing phone format or number format - I wanna delete all things except number( or text), then I need put some text\numeric\sight into new number\text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example :

```
var formulaTargetCell = SpreadsheetApp
.getActiveSpreadsheet()
.getActiveSheet()
.getRange(1, 1, 1, 1); 

formulaTargetCell.setFormula('=ArrayFormula(replace(replace(regexreplace(K1:K&"""",""[-/,. ()]"",""""),4,0,""-""),8,0,""-""))');

//or

var formulaTargetCell = SpreadsheetApp
.getActiveSpreadsheet()
.getActiveSheet()
.getRange('B2');

formulaTargetCell.setFormulaR1C1('=ArrayFormula(replace(replace(regexreplace(K1:K&"""",""[-/,. ()]"",""""),4,0,""-""),8,0,""-""))');
```

There are still some kind of way to set formula in app script that documented in [available API of Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: I'm appreciated for your answer but it still doesn't work. I was trying it before and problem is - syntaxes of formulas, so it's mean we couldn't use this type of formula in existing format for using by script.

Comment: @Borgis, sorry that I didn't check your formula at beginning, now I think you should escape your double quote by prepending double quote, just edited the answer, have a try!

Comment: The double quotes are fine.
Let me clarify just a little:
This is example of a result:
"(22)road.CA" - "22-road-CA"; 
"22roadCA" - is not(eror).

Comment: @Borgis, maybe you could edit and update the question with comment above. With question being more detailed, it may get more help from others.

Comment: value = value.replace(/^ /, '').replace(/[. )]/g, 'a').replace(/[+]/g, '').replace(/(aa)/g, '-').replace(/(a)/g, '-').replace(/[(]/g, '-');
    value = value.replace(/^-/, '');
    value = value.replace(/-$/, '');  
    range2.setValue(value);

Comment: Sr for code in wrong format but i doesn't know how to insert it right :'(

Comment: Never mind, just prepend and append  " ` " to embrace your code block, but I still suggest move these comments to question.